# How do I get my tag to open from the center, rather than from the left?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to have a pane in my site that will open from the center and gradually open once loaded. I have it set up to do that, but it starts from the left where the tag starts, and not from the center where I would like it to start. How do I start it from the center?

I have tried aligning it to the center and adjusting from there, but it doesnt seem to work well enough for my positioning.

```css
#cBox{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: -.5%;
 margin-bottom: -1%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 80%;
 border-right: 3px ridge;
 border-left: 3px ridge;
 border-color: #A17500;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black); 
 overflow-y: scroll;
 animation: open 1s;
}
@keyframes open {
 0% {width: 0%}
 100% {width: 80%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="cBox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `left` which works in the same animation, so as the width expands, the left reduces.

As you're already dealing with `margin-left:10%`, I've started the `left:40%` and finished with `left:0` to compensate...

```css
#cBox{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: -.5%;
  margin-bottom: -1%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-right: 3px ridge;
  border-left: 3px ridge;
  border-color: #A17500;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black); 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  animation: open 1s;
  left: 0;
}
@keyframes open {
  0% {width: 0%; left: 40%;}
  100% {width: 80%; left: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="cBox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
margin:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
```

to center it and keep the animation as it is:

```css
#cBox {
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin-top: -.5%;
  margin-bottom: -1%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  border-right: 3px ridge;
  border-left: 3px ridge;
  border-color: #A17500;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  animation: open 1s;
}

@keyframes open {
  0% {
    width: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cBox">
</div>
```

Comment: Clever, easier than my suggestion